IAM Condition via Principal Tag not working
I have an app built in AWS Amplify that uses a cognito user pool for my user base.
In the associated identity pool, I have gone to the Attributes for access control subtab and am using the default mappings. I was having trouble with custom attributes from the user pool so I thought I would get it working with default mappings first.
username - sub client - aud
I am now trying to set a condition using these attributes, condition below:
"Condition": {
"StringLike": {
"aws:PrincipalTag/username": "users_sub_value"
}
}
I get the below error message when trying to run my operation : Error AccessDeniedException: User: <<ASSUMED_ROLE>> is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: <<DYNAMO_TABLE>> because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:PutItem action
I have tried using the below, just in case but that throws the same issue
"Condition": {
"StringLike": {
"aws:PrincipalTag/username": "*"
}
}
I have done a Null check as well but same issue.
Can anyone shed any light on why this may be happening, or what I may have missed? Is there any way for me to debug what is actually present in the PrincipalTag as well, as currently I am stumped because I have no idea of actually figuring out why the condition is failing in the first place because I do not know what is present "aws:PrincipalTag/username"

It appears the issue is related to the role that is being assumed.  Try testing using the aws cli for sts. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/
Use a Cognito test user and then assume-role. however, either way the role you are assuming needs to have the action dynamodb:PutItem for the proper dynamo_table resource. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazondynamodb.html

Hiya Eric, thanks for your response.
Just to clarify, the PutItem permission is already there and working fine, removing the condition allows the action through, so it's something to do with that principal tag!
Does the aws cli allow me to see what is present (if anything) in the principal tag of the session? Currently I cannot think of another way forward as if I have no idea what is in there I cannot really debug the issue further.

As a separate example I was looking at this link If the principal tag was working as expected, would you expect the attributes mapped to appear directly in the claims tag? Would that be a good way of looking at what is available in the PrincipalTag?

Not really :(  I would use  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html
I just know that the role that is being assumed is saying it doesn't have access.  So I would try to ensure that the role works with the above policy simulator, maybe without the condition, then add that in. ensure you also do not have a deny anywhere because that would trump everything.

Thanks for that Eric, I actually already have had a go at that policy simulator!  The good news is that if the principal tag attribute has the correct value, the action is allowed! I have changed it to use a custom attribute instead in the policy, which allows the above to work.
It is clear to me then that the principal tag does not have the attributes it has been set up to carry over during the session. Is there anything that could be preventing this from happening? I have the SessionTag permission and the attributes mapped.
